# getComputedStyle does not work on first page load

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-ref

I'm making use of React useRef and useEffect. Essentially the useEffect checks if the the element in question has a certain style. If it does, then it set's the state of something else. This doesn't work when you first load the application and I get the error

**'TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'**

But when I refresh the page, it works? Is anyone able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
const foodTypeSection = useRef();
const [isFoodTypeSectionVisible, setIsFoodTypeSectionVisible] = useState(true);
    
useEffect(() => {
    const styles = getComputedStyle(foodTypeSection.current);
    
    if (styles.display == 'none') {
        setIsFoodTypeSectionVisible(false);
    }
}, [foodTypeSection]);


return (
    <Section>
      <Contained>
        <Form ......>
          {({ setFieldValue }) => (
            <div ref={foodTypeSection}>
              <h4>Food</h4>
            </div>
          )}
        </Form>
      </Contained>
    </Section>
)
```

Comment: Add `foodTypeSection` to the `useEffect()` deps (`[foodTypeSection]`).

Comment: @code Tried this but I still get the same error.

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: @code I've updated the code in my question.

Comment: Huh, see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)...

Comment: @code Weirdly but when I take it out of the <Form> component then everything works. I guess there's something within that component that is causing it not to work.

Comment: The reason is when you call `useRef`, `ref.current` doesn't immediately get defined, which means you have to wait a bit to access the DOM element. I would remove the effect and simply write `if(ref.current) {...}`.

Comment: @code If I do that, then on the first load it completely ignores it :/ Here's the code.        

if (foodTypeSection.current) {
    const styles = getComputedStyle(foodTypeSection.current);

    if (styles.display == 'none') {
      setIsFoodTypeSectionVisible(false);
    }
  }

Comment: In your effect can you try logging `foodTypeSection.current`? (and remove the `foodTypeSection` dep.)

Comment: @code On initial load I get undefined. When I refresh the page, I get the markup

Answer (score 0):

The effect will not run again if the node that the ref is attached to changes, so even if it worked it wouldn’t do what you want. In order to have some code run everytime a node changes, you can use a callback ref, but even then, your code will most likely not run again if the css changes for some unrelated reason.

The root issue here is that using `getComputedStyle` to change a React variable is an anti-pattern in React. Most likely you're the one setting the css in one way or another, therefore you should be able to determine whether the div is visible inside React, without having to ask the DOM.

*Edit:*

Here is how to delay the `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const styles = getComputedStyle(foodTypeSection.current);
    
        if (styles.display == 'none') {
            setIsFoodTypeSectionVisible(false);
        }
    }, 42);
}, []);
```

Comment: The reason I'm asking the DOM is because Google Optimize is adding the style to a reusable component so I'm trying to figure out if the ref in question has that style applied and so I won't have the ability to change this style. Is there no other solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know Google Optimize, but I guess you could use a setTimeout to wait some amount of time hoping that it will be enough for the ref to be initialized. But it’s a hack and will probably not work very well. React is not designed to be used together with a library that modifies the same part of the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll have to keep looking to find a solution.

Comment: Any help on how I can delay the useEffect?

Comment: @Mazmius See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Still get the error so will have to look again.